# Rails ActiveRecord id = xyz works but id != xyz does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-and-belongs-to-many

This works:

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
@users_cities = @user.cities
```

This does NOT work:

```
@other_users = User.where("id != ?", 1)
@users_cities = @other_users.cities
```

However, I can run the second example from the console and it works fine.

Here's the error:

```
NoMethodError in CitiesController#index
undefined method `cities' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f8f670f2870>
app/controllers/cities_controller.rb:23:in `index'
```

Line 23 is this one:

```
@users_cities = @other_users.cities
```

Models are just `has_and_belongs_to_many :cities` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :user`.  I thought that `has_and_belongs_to_many :user` was meant to be `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` but I get the same error (even after restarting the server).

Comment: The issue is you're trying to call `cities` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (which is what is returned by `where`). The `cities` relation is only on an instance of `User`. Perhaps you're really trying to ask: "how do I return all cities related to some group of users"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `.first` to `ActiveRecord::Relation` object

```
@other_users = User.where("id != ?", 1).first
@users_cities = @other_users.cities
```

`User.find_by_id(1)` is a instance of `User` Model.

`User.where(:id => 1)` is not of `User` Model but `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Answer (score 1):

In the former case it works fine because, **@user** points to a **userobject**. Assuming that your user model has the following attributes(id, name, created_at, updated_at).

```
@user= User.find(current_user.id)
@user.class
 => User(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, etc)
@user
  => #<User id: 1, name: "Amar",created_at: "2013-07-10 10:07:37", updated_at: "2013-07-10 10:07:37">
```

So now your instance variable **@user** points to a **userobject** and so the following works.

```
@users_cities = @user.cities
```

But in case of **where**, it is a relation and the instance variable holds an **array** having a **single record**.

```
@user= User.where(:id => current_user.id)
@user.class
  => ActiveRecord::Relation
@user
  => [#<User id: 1, name: "Amar", created_at: "2013-07-10 10:07:37", updated_at: "2013-07-10 10:07:37">]
```

Here, **@user** is not pointing to a **userobject** and hence you cant get the cities assoicted with that user. You can try the following.

```
@user= User.where(:id => current_user.id).first #first gets the first object from the array.
@user.class
 => User(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, etc)
@user
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Amar",created_at: "2013-07-10 10:07:37", updated_at: "2013-07-10 10:07:37">
```

In this case the following should work because your instance variable **@user** have made to point to a **single userobject** by using **first**.

```
@users_cities = @user.cities
```

Again in your case, your are getting an array from User model

```
@other_users = User.where("id != ?", 1)
```

It will collect an array of elements. So you have to iterate over the array to find its cities.

```
@other_users.each do |user|
 # do manipulation with user.cities
end
```

In this case if you use **first** then it will point only to the **first object** in the array. **So iterate through it to cover all the other users**.

Answer (score 0):

@other_users return array of users not a single user object.you need to iterate through all objects to get cities

Use map

> @users_cities = @other_users.map(&:cities) => [[city1, city 2], [city3, city4]]

if you want to have a flat array then user flattern

> @users_cities = @other_users.map(&:cities).flatten

the other option is to select cities from City model not via association. something like

> @users_cities = City.where("user_id != 1")